# Right syntax for this simple inline style sheet media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

what would be equivalent to following external style sheet

```
<link href="_css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
```

Is it would be this

```
@media screen,projection
{
}
```

or this

```
@media screen,@media projection
{
}
```

or something else.

Comment: Option "A" ought to do the trick.

Comment: @rjz are you sure because i wasn't able to find syntax of it on google.

Comment: Fairly :-) see the W3C spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the first one:

```
@media screen, projection
{
}
```

The `@media` token only appears once for a single media block.